# Required option on RepeatedType field

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a form used for registration. In this form, I have this field :

```
->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, ['type' => PasswordType::class,
    'first_options' => ['label' => 'Mot de passe'],
    'second_options' => ['label' => 'Confirmation du mot de passe'],
    'invalid_message' => 'Erreur de mot de passe',
    'required' => true
])
```

When I try to submit this form leaving both password fields empty it is still submitting the form and throws an invalid constraint error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user .... : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'password' cannot be null
```

The input rendering gives:

```
<input type="password" id="field_plainPassword_first" name="field[plainPassword][first]" required="required">
<input type="password" id="field_plainPassword_second" name="field[plainPassword][second]" required="required">
```

In Controller :

```
$user = new Tutore();
$event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
$this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);
$form = $this->createForm(RegistrationTutoreFormType::class, null);
$form->setData($user);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $username = $em->getRepository(Tutore::class)->getNewUsername(100000, 200000, 0);
        $user->setUsername($username);
        $user->setNom(ucfirst(strtolower($form->get('nom')->getData())));
        $user->setPrenom(ucfirst(strtolower($form->get('prenom')->getData())));
        $user->setEmail(strtolower($form->get('email')->getData()));
        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {     
            return $this->render('User/Registration/check_email.html.twig', ['user' => $user]);
        }
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
        return $response;
    }

    $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
    $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);

    if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
        return $response;
    }
}

return $this->render('User/Registration/tutore.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
```

Any idea why?

Comment: can you add the error you get?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Can you also add the function in the controller that saves the user? :)

Comment: I added it. I'm using FOS with a custom registration controller and form.